# Swift: load images Async in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, haneke

I have a `tableview` that I created with code (without `storyboard`):

```
class MSContentVerticalList: MSContent,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
var tblView:UITableView!
var dataSource:[MSC_VCItem]=[]

init(Frame: CGRect,DataSource:[MSC_VCItem]) {
    super.init(frame: Frame)
    self.dataSource = DataSource
    tblView = UITableView(frame: Frame, style: .Plain)
    tblView.delegate = self
    tblView.dataSource = self
    self.addSubview(tblView)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    let record = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = record.Title
    cell.imageView!.downloadFrom(link: record.Icon, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit)
    cell.imageView!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    print(cell.imageView!.frame)
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = record.SubTitle
    return cell
}
}
```

and in other class I have an extension method for download images Async:

```
   extension UIImageView
{
    func downloadFrom(link link:String?, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode)
    {
        contentMode = mode
        if link == nil
        {
            self.image = UIImage(named: "default")
            return
        }
        if let url = NSURL(string: link!)
        {
            print("\nstart download: \(url.lastPathComponent!)")
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, _, error) -> Void in
                guard let data = data where error == nil else {
                    print("\nerror on download \(error)")
                    return
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                    print("\ndownload completed \(url.lastPathComponent!)")
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
        else
        {
            self.image = UIImage(named: "default")
        }
    }
}
```

I used this function in other places and worked correctly, Based on my logs I understand that images downloaded without problem (when the cell is rendered) and after download of image, The cell UI not updated.

Also I tried to use caching library like [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) but problem is exist and not change.

Please help me to understand mistakes

Thanks

Comment: It seems you are downloading image but not adding into your cell image view. Also `downloadFrom` have 2 argument but you passed 3 argument in cellForRow. It must throw error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After setting the image you should call `self.layoutSubviews()`

edit: corrected from `setNeedsLayout` to `layoutSubviews`

Comment: You should not call this method directly. From the apple documentation, call layoutIfNeeded() or setNeedsLayout() instead.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews

Answer (score 11):

The issue is that the `.subtitle` rendition of `UITableViewCell` will layout the cell as soon as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns (overriding your attempt to set the `frame` of the image view). Thus, if you are asynchronously retrieving the image, the cell will be re-laid out as if there was no image to show (because you're not initializing the image view's `image` property to anything), and when you update the `imageView` asynchronously later, the cell will have already been laid out in a manner such that you won't be able to see the image you downloaded.

There are a couple of solutions here:

1. You can have the `download` update the image to `default` not only when there is no URL, but also when there is a URL (so you'll first set it to the default image, and later update the image to the one that you downloaded from the network):

   ```swift
   extension UIImageView {
       func download(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFill, placeholder: UIImage? = nil) {
           contentMode = mode
           image = placeholder
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
               guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, error == nil else {
                   print("error on download \(error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))")
                   return
               }
               guard 200 ..< 300 ~= response.statusCode else {
                   print("statusCode != 2xx; \(response.statusCode)")
                   return
               }
               guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                   print("not valid image")
                   return
               }
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   print("download completed \(url.lastPathComponent)")
                   self.image = image
               }
           }.resume()
       }
   }
   ```

   This ensures that the cell will be laid out for the presence of an image, regardless, and thus the asynchronous updating of the image view will work (sort of: see below).
2. Rather than using the dynamically laid out `.subtitle` rendition of `UITableViewCell`, you can also create your own cell prototype which is laid out appropriately with a fixed size for the image view. That way, if there is no image immediately available, it won't reformat the cell as if there was no image available. This gives you complete control over the formatting of the cell using autolayout.
3. You can also define your `downloadFrom` method to take an additional third parameter, a closure that you'll call when the download is done. Then you can do a `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` inside that closure. This assumes, though, that you fix this code to cache downloaded images (in a `NSCache` for example), so that you can check to see if you have a cached image before downloading again.

Having said that, as I alluded to above, there are some problems with this basic pattern:

1. If you scroll down and then scroll back up, you are going to re-retrieve the image from the network. You really want to cache the previously downloaded images before retrieving them again.

Ideally, your server's response headers are configured properly so that the built in `NSURLCache` will take care of this for you, but you'd have to test that. Alternatively, you might cache the images yourself in your own `NSCache`.

2. If you scroll down quickly to, say, the 100th row, you really don't want the visible cells backlogged behind image requests for the first 99 rows that are no longer visible. You really want to cancel requests for cells that scroll off screen. (Or use `dequeueCellForRowAtIndexPath`, where you re-use cells, and then you can write code to cancel the previous request.)
3. As mentioned above, you really want to do `dequeueCellForRowAtIndexPath` so that you don't have to unnecessarily instantiate `UITableViewCell` objects. You should be reusing them.

Personally, I might suggest that you (a) use `dequeueCellForRowAtIndexPath`, and then (b) marry this with one of the well established `UIImageViewCell` categories such as [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage), [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), [DFImageManager](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager) or [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). To do the necessary caching and cancelation of prior requests is a non-trivial exercise, and using one of those `UIImageView` extensions will simplify your life. And if you're determined to do this yourself, you might want to still look at some of the code for those extensions, so you can pick-up ideas on how to do this properly.

--

For example, using [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage), you can:

1. Define a custom table view cell subclass:

   ```swift
   class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
       @IBOutlet weak var customImageView: UIImageView!
       @IBOutlet weak var customTitleLabel: UILabel!
       @IBOutlet weak var customSubtitleLabel: UILabel!
   }
   ```
2. Add a cell prototype to your table view storyboard, specifying (a) a base class of `CustomCell`; (b) a storyboard id of `CustomCell`; (c) add image view and two labels to your cell prototype, hooking up the `@IBOutlets` to your `CustomCell` subclass; and (d) add whatever constraints necessary to define the placement/size of the image view and two labels.

   You can use autolayout constraints to define dimensions of the image view
3. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, can then do something like:

   ```swift
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

       let record = dataSource[indexPath.row]
       cell.customTitleLabel.text = record.title
       cell.customSubtitleLabel.text = record.subtitle
       if let url = record.url {
           cell.customImageView.af.setImage(withURL: url)
       }

       return cell
   }
   ```

   With that, you enjoy not only basic asynchronous image updating, but also image caching, prioritization of visible images because we're reusing dequeued cell, it's more efficient, etc. And by using a cell prototype with constraints and your custom table view cell subclass, everything is laid out correctly, saving you from manually adjusting the `frame` in code.

The process is largely the same regardless of which of these `UIImageView` extensions you use, but the goal is to get you out of the weeds of writing the extension yourself.

Comment: BTW, in the above code samples, I've preserved your property names of `Title`, `SubTitle`, and `Icon`, but you really should be conforming to Cocoa naming conventions, starting property names with lowercase letters.

Comment: That third approach, calling `reloadCells...` works perfectly fine, as long as `cellForRow...` retrieves everything it needs the first time and only lays out everything the second time. In fact, sometimes this is the only approach that works and it provides the ability to easily control the animation. But you're right, that if you do it incorrectly, you could end up with infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3):

oh my god, the layoutSubviews is not recommended to use directly
the right way to solve the problem is call:
`[self setNeedsLayout];`
`[self layoutIfNeeded];`
here, the two way have to call together.
try this, have a good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own cell by subclassing UITableViewCell. The style .Subtitle, which you are using, has no image view, even if the property is available. Only the style UITableViewCellStyleDefault has an image view.

Comment: This is not true. The `.Subtitle` cell supports image views, too. The issue is that the cell is laid out according to whether there was an image present when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns (at he has left it as `nil`) and supplying the `image` asynchronously is not enough for the cell to be reformatted properly when the image is downloaded. The simplest solution is to provide a placeholder image (thus the cell will be laid out correctly) and the asynchronous image update will basically work correctly.